# Change text color based on property in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

How would I go about accomplishing this using Blazor?

I am using powershell to pull all active forwards from Microsoft Exchange, and I would like to display an icon with a different color if forward to both property is set. So if forward.SendToBoth equals true the oi-arrow-thick-right should be blue, if it is disabled it should be grey.

```
<tbody>
            @foreach (var forward in activeForwards)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forward.DisplayName</td>
                    <td>@forward.PrimarySmtpAddress</td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <span class="oi oi-arrow-thick-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => HandleRemoveAction(forward)">X</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>@forward.ForwardToDisplay</td>
                    <td>@forward.ForwardToEmail</td>
                </tr>
            }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using bootstrap classes:

```
<span class="oi oi-arrow-thick-right @(forward.SendToBoth ? "text-primary" : "text-muted")" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

or you can create your own css styles to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that returns a string containing the css color.

```cs
 <span class="oi oi-arrow-thick-right" 
       style="color: @GetCssColour(forward.SendToBoth);" ... />
...

@code {
    private string GetCssColour(bool sendToBoth)
        => sendToBoth ? "blue" : "gray"; 
}
```